# Group button is not showing properly in inner html

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here in the JavaScript inner html i'm trying to show two buttons horizontally using Bootstrap Button Group. Like this picture[image: Bootstrap group button i want like this]

But actually it is showing just 1 button appearing like this.
[image: Bootstrap group button that is appearing]

Though it works fine in HTML but don't know why is it creating problem in inner HTML. Here goes the JavaScript code snippet

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.className = 'row';
div.innerHTML = '<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: #b5ffaa; height: auto; width: auto"\
                <div class="row"\
                <br>\
                <div class="col-sm-8">\
                <h2 style="color: #000000">' + name + '</h2>\
                <h3 style="color: #000000">' + type + '</h3>\
                <h4 style="color: #000000">Salary: ' + sal + '</h4>\
                <h4 style="color: #000000">Location: ' + d[0] + ',' + d[1] + ',' + d[2] + ',' + d[3] + ',' + d[4] + ',' + d[5] +'</h4>\
                <br>\
                </div>\
                <br><br><br>\
                <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg">\
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="job_info()" href="#jobdetails">More Details</button>\
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Apply</button>\
                </div>\
                </div><br></div>';

document.getElementById('content').appendChild(div);
```

Comment: To start with, seems like you are missing some closing brackets (>) on your first two div elements

Comment: I corrected that but still it is the same...

Comment: seems to work fine here https://jsfiddle.net/gLw9bj7n/

Comment: It works perfectly and so my code in HTML file. But inside the JavaScript file in inner HTML it is not working.

Comment: still works fine here using js https://jsfiddle.net/gLw9bj7n/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it works fine here https://jsfiddle.net/gLw9bj7n/3/
but probably your code doesnt have created or doesnt have the scope access the the variables `d, name, type, sal`